# How to add XML tags new file using an existing text file in python?

Tags: python, xml, text-files

So the problem I have is that I need to be able to take an existing text file and make a new file adding xml tags to each line.  For example:

```
Hello
World
This
Is
The
Text
```

should be written to a new text file like this

```
<tag1>Hello</tag1>
<tag2>World</tag2>
<tag3>This</tag3>
<tag4>Is</tag4>
<tag5>The</tag5>
<tag6>Text</tag6>
```

I know how to open and write to a new file but having trouble manipulating the data, I'm still a noob and this is my first question on stackoverflow so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you want way to do simply, open the text file with vim and type following.

```
:%s!\(.*\)!\=printf("<tag%d>%s</tag%d>", line("."), submatch(1), line("."))!g
```

Or if you want to use python,

```
from xml.sax.saxutils import escape
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
  print "\n".join((lambda y: ["<tag%d>%s</tag%d>" % (i+1, escape(y[i].strip()), i+1) for i in range(0, len(y))])(f.readlines()))
```

Also an answer from @goncalopp

```
from xml.sax.saxutils import escape
for i,line in enumerate(open('file.txt')):
  print "<tag{0}>{1}</tag{0}>".format(i+1,escape(line.strip()))
```

Comment: That looks over complicated. There's no need to import and learn a whole library for something this simple

Comment: @goncalopp used for `escape()`.

Comment: Yes, I noticed. Nothing the OP has posted suggests the need for escaping, IMHO. If he **needs** escaping later, he'll learn about it, instead of avoiding the problem. It's not just the library, though; compare the readability of your solution to this: `for i,line in enumerate(open('file.txt')): print "<tag{0}>{1}</tag{0}>".format(i,line) `. Lambdas and list comprehensions have their place, but won't help a self-entitled noob

Answer (score 1):

This is a very simple problem that you should be able to solve on your own. 
Since you're having some trouble, I'll show you how to, generally, attack most programming problems.

First, **divide** the problem.
You have a text file which you must modify to include xml tags. You've correctly identified that opening and writing to files are *separate* problems - and you already know how to solve those. Futhermore, it's obvious but worth mentioning that you're dealing with a similar repeating pattern *on each line*. So, if you know how to transform each line of the text into what you want, you'll have solved the problem. Now, let's look at that first line:

```
Hello
```

becomes

```
<tag1>Hello</tag1>
```

What steps must be performed in order to transform one into the other? Well, the second is just the first with some text inserted at the beggining and end of the string! This is called *string concatenation*, and simply googling will find you an answer immediately. 
Further, you have the issue of the tag number, which is different on each line. This is solved by keeping a *counter* variable, converting the number to a string, and concatenating it too.

Here's an example of a counter:

```
for i in range(10):
    print i
```

and another:

```
i=0
while i<10:
    print i
    i+=1
```

That's it. I'm confident that you can solve the problem on your own now.

Answer (score -1):

```
>>> f = open('file.txt', 'r')
>>> lines = f.readlines()
>>> for index in range(len(lines)):
...     print '<tag%s>%s</tag%s>'%(index+1, lines[index].strip(), index+1)
... 
<tag1>Hello</tag1>
<tag2>World</tag2>
<tag3>This</tag3>
<tag4>Is</tag4>
<tag5>The</tag5>
<tag6>Text</tag6>
Hope you know how to write into file.
```